# C programming reading from file using functions & calloc

Tags: c, function, calloc

I am having trouble utilizing functions to get the second calloc of my program to read from file work correctly. The function to be called is `colAlloc (variables)`.

My code below is:

```
void readSpaces (FILE * ptrF, char fileN [], double ** m, int * r)
{
    ptrF = fopen (fileN, "r");

    char s;
    int i;
    int ctrS = 0;
    int c;
    int cVal;

    for (s = getc (ptrF); s != EOF; s = getc (ptrF))
    {
        if (s == ' ' || s == '\t' || s == '\t')
        {
            ++ctrS;
        }
    }
    cVal = ctrS / * r;

    c = cVal;

    colAlloc (ptrF, fileN, m, &r, &cVal);

    /**something is not working here so the program is giving a run-time error once it needs to read column**/

    fclose (ptrF);
}

//allocate memory for column
void colAlloc (FILE * ptrF, char fileN [], double ** m, int ** r, int ** s) //file pointer, file name, matrix, row, spaces;
{
    int i;
    int c;

    c = & s;

    for (i = 0; i < * r; i ++ )
    {
        m [i] = (double *) calloc (c, sizeof (double));
        if (m [i] == NULL)
        {
            printf ("\nSorry, not enough memory!\n\n");
            exit (0);
        }
    }
    printf ("Cols >> %d.\n\n", c);

    for (i = 0; i < * r; i ++)
    {
        free (m [i]);
    }

}
```

When I call the function in the `readSpaces (ptrF, fileN, m, r)` function, the program just crashes.  **I think I am calling the function wrong, and is confusing the use of pointers and call by reference for the appropriate variables.**

Some help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Aside `char s;` ==> `int s;` the beginner's error is to assume that a character is type `char`. Please read the man page for functions you use, to see what type to use which for `getc` is `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < * r; i ++ )
```

r is of `int **`, so `i < *r` compares an int (`i`) to an `int *` (`*r`). In other words you are comparing against an address, which is not what you intended.

Comment: So far I am able to get the program to compile with no warning messages, however I am still getting a run-time error. My error is now most likely in the function `colAlloc (...)`. Any suggestions?